# How to fill map boundaries with external images?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, geom

I am creating a map of Brazil with its state boundaries, which is straight forward to achieve using `ggplot2` and `geom_sf`.

However, this time around, instead of color filling each state with data, I want to fill each state's boundaries with an external image (png), similar to [this](https://online.olivet.edu/sites/default/files/styles/no_style/public/images/largest-employers-map.png?itok=060UQdeu) example of the largest employer in each state.

[image]

I have tried a few settings of `geom_image` and even `geom_flag` to no avail (hence why I am not posting any code here).

Are there any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Comment: ggpattern might be what you're looking for. https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/articles/pattern-image.html  It'll likely take some work merging connected polygons to look like the above map.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `cartography::getPngLayer/pngLayer`. These two functions takes a png as input, geotag and crop it to the shape of a given polygon and creates a `rasterbrick` object (as a tile) that you can manipulate and plot:

https://dieghernan.github.io/cartographyvignette#png-layer

[image]