# Overlay/Fill country boundaries with image in

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

Is there a way to fill a country with an image similar to R solution using custom library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318505/how-to-fill-map-boundaries-with-external-images):

I have a solution where the face colour is filled for instance the below where Italy is blue. However, I would like to add the Italian flag. Is there a way in Python (I have not found much after searching) or is something like QGIS needed:

```
#create a map where I can load images in to fill the countries
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader

flag = "italy.png" #this is a locally saved png.

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15)) #size of plot
ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.TransverseMercator(25))
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=1)
ax.coastlines(resolution='110m') #simplifies the border lines
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, facecolor="#40e0d0") #colour of ocean
# ax.gridlines() #adds global grid lines
ax.set_extent ((-7.5, 50, 34, 69), cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()) #makes it european


shpfilename = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='110m',
                                      category='cultural',
                                      name='admin_0_countries')

for country in shpreader.Reader(shpfilename).records():
    if country.attributes['NAME_LONG'] == "Italy":
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                          facecolor="blue",
                          #no attribute like this img= "fd",

                          label=country.attributes['NAME_LONG'])

plt.show()
```

Any help, much appreciated!

Comment: FYI. For a new user, you can't vote up my answer until you gain 25? reputation points. But you can mark it “accepted”, and earn "+2" reputation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo code that does what you need. As a matter of fact, `cartopy logo` uses this technique to create.

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np

imdat1 = plt.imread('flag-of-italy.jpg', format='jpg') # use your flag

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.TransverseMercator(25))
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=1)
ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, facecolor="#40e0d0")
# ax.gridlines() #adds global grid lines
ax.set_extent ((-7.5, 50, 24, 69), cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())

shpfilename = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='110m',
                                      category='cultural',
                                      name='admin_0_countries')

italy_ctry = None  #use this to grab italy's

for country in shpreader.Reader(shpfilename).records():
    if country.attributes['NAME_LONG'] == "Italy":
        italy_ctry = country
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                          facecolor="none",
                          alpha=0.7,
                          zorder=2,
                          label=country.attributes['NAME_LONG'])

# create mpatch from `italy` geometry
cg = italy_ctry.geometry
cg2 = cg.simplify(0.02)

if cg2.geometryType()=='MultiPolygon':
    # if == `Polygon`, dont need to loop
    for ea in cg2.geoms:
        cg2xy = ea.exterior.xy  # tuple of (x,y)
        xys = []
        for ea in zip(cg2xy[0], cg2xy[1]):
            #print(ea[0],ea[1])
            xys.append([ea[0],ea[1]])

        # add a patch
        poly = mpatches.Polygon(xys, closed=True, ec='r', \
                                lw=2, fc='yellow', \
                                transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), \
                                alpha=0.5, zorder=30)

        plate_carree_transform = ccrs.PlateCarree()._as_mpl_transform(ax)

        xtent1 = (6.519950, 17.122259, 35.783370, 47.962952)
        imdat2 = ax.imshow(imdat1, origin='upper', extent=xtent1, \
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), \
            zorder=15, alpha=.9)

        ##imdat2 = ax.stock_img()  #for testing
        imdat2.set_clip_path(mpatches.Path(xys), transform=plate_carree_transform) 
    pass

plt.show()
```

The sample plot (varies with the flag in use):

[image: italy_wflag]

Comment: appreciated. Where are you pulling the xtent1 values from for the overlay extent? If it were to be dynamic and say I replaced Italy with Spain surely these values would have to change too? thanks

Comment: @Andrew  Each `country.geometry` provides coordinates that can be processed to get its LL and UR corners. I didn't do that in the code but read them on a map. It is a good question that you can post as a new question.

Comment: Thanks, LL and UR: lower left and upper right? I suspect other two are low right and up right? Just to confirm, what do you mean by read them on a map? How have you sourced these figures - from calculating them from the output of country.geometry? thanks I will ask this after confirmations

Comment: thanks, where did you get/how did you calculate the xtent1 figures though? was it from another answer or something similar? thanks

Comment: @Andrew For exact LL/UR (corners) boundary of Italy, you can use `cg.bounds` and get (lonmin,latmin,lonmax,latmax) in degrees. In my code, I use crude values of that.